# Prevent scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll

Is there any way to prevent ONLY scrolling up within a document (including touch devices)? In this example the user will only have the ability to scroll down.

This is what I'm currently using but this disables all scroll.

```
$('.example').on('touchmove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why in heaven's name do that to your users?

Comment: Hahaha! I know what you're thinking but, I'm not trying to trick my users. It's just a problem I'm having with smaller devices and an angular widget I implemented. It's a 'swipe down' card div [link](http://codepen.io/adamaoc/pen/wBcpq?editors=1010) which takes up 100% width of the screen. 

This widget needs to prevent the document from scrolling vertically, so the user can swipe down cards. But on smaller devices, where the div cuts off, the user can't see the bottom of the cards. So in this case, I only need to disable scrolling up when the user swipes down a card.